# How to use depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb nodelet with rosbag?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sorry to post such a simple question but I found little references on the web. I have a couple of rosbags recorded with the following topics and I want to take rgb and depth topics to form point clouds in the data type of sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.

```
topics:       /camera/depth/camera_info   49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo        
              /camera/depth/image         49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image             
              /camera/depth/points        49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2       
              /camera/rgb/camera_info     49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo        
              /camera/rgb/image_color     49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image             
              /camera/rgb/points          49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2       
              /cortex_marker_array        49 msgs    : visualization_msgs/MarkerArray
              /imu                        49 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu               
              /tf                         49 msgs    : tf/tfMessage
```

And from the  [depth_image_proc ROS Wiki documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc#depth_image_proc.2BAC8-point_cloud_xyzrgb) provided here, I understood that I need to remap the corresponding topics so to get the point clouds. I followed the instruction of [nodelet - ROS Wiki](https://gist.github.com/bhaskara/2400165) and example such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/bhaskara/2400165) to write my launch file. However, once I played my rosbag and then launched my nodelet launch file, the rosbag play node and the point_xyzrgb won't accept any topics whatsoever.  So, what is the proper way so to make topics recorded in a rosbag to play as PointCloud2? Thanks !

What I did was the following:

```
$ rosbag play my_rosbag.bag
```

and then launched my launch file which is as follows:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="rgb_camera_info" value="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
  <arg name="rgb_rimg_ect" value="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>  <!--Rectified color image-->
  <arg name="depReg_imgrect" value="/camera/depth/image"/>  <!--Rectified depth image-->
  <arg name="out_cloud" value="camera/depth_registered/points"/>

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet" args="manager" output="screen"/>

  <!-- Construct point cloud of the rgb and depth topics -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="points_xyzrgb" args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb standalone_nodelet --no-bond">
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg rgb_camera_info)" />  
    <remap from="rgb/image_rect_color" to="$(arg rgb_rimg_ect)"/>  
    <remap from="depth_registered/image_rect" to="$(arg depReg_imgrect)"/>  
    <remap from="depth_registered/points" to="$(arg out_cloud)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216748/how-to-use-depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb-nodelet-with-rosbag?/) by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2015-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a good tutorial on that here: [BagRecordingPlayback](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback). It also works with openni2, not only openni. For openni2, this script + launch file does the trick:

**record-rosbag.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
rosbag record \
   /tf \
   /camera/rgb/image_raw \
   /camera/rgb/camera_info \
   /camera/depth_registered/image_raw \
   /camera/depth_registered/camera_info
```

**depth+rgb_to_pointcloud.launch:**

```
<launch>
  <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />

  <include file="$(find openni2_launch)/launch/openni2.launch">
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="true" />
    <arg name="load_driver" value="false" />
    <arg name="publish_tf" value="false" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2016-04-28**:
Well answered, @Martin Günther ! But where to find multisensor_tracking_ros? I only found [ethzasl_sensor_fusion](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_sensor_fusion) when I tried to google it.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-05-02**:
Sorry, that was a copy-paste error. You don't need the package `multisensor_tracking_ros`, I've removed that from my answer.

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2016-05-05**:
OK! Got it ! Thank you so much !